# GitlabCI thow AIX server

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, aix

Im in a new proyect that is migrate a repo to gitlab and then install the runner into the server AIX to compile the components.
I was investigating and the gitlab runner is not compatible with AIX.
Any suggestions??
Someone work with pipelines in AIX servers?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We work with Gitlab pipelines on AIX. There is a port of Gitlab Runner to AIX - https://www.power-devops.com/gitlab